# Prevent two paragraphs from separating across a page break in Indesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, paragraph

I know one can use the **Keep** feature to prevent widows and orphans in Indesign but I have a slightly related issue that seems to defy this workaround. I have two paragraphs as below:

```
Word (paragraph 1)
Synonyms, meanings (paragraph 2)
```

Both paragraphs are single line texts with different paragraph styles applied to them.

I need to ensure both paragraphs stick together in case they happen to straddle a page break. Is there any way to ensure this in Indesign?

Answer (score 2):

In the paragraph style Keep Options for "Word" (you *are* using paragraph styles, right?) use "Keep with next" and give a value of one line. Anywhere this paragraph style appears, it will not permit the following paragraph to flow to the next column or page.